# Spatial analysis: How to find region most prone to storm loss when only have loss data for whole region?

Tags: regression, correlation, geostatistics

I'm thinking about a statistical problem and I would be grateful if you could give me some hints of how I could address this problem:

I have data of n insurance companies and for each insurance company I have:

- The number of buildings per postal code (here let's assume the vulnerability of each building is the same and that there are also no differences between the insurance companies). Each insurance company has buildings in more than one postal code (but not necessarily in each postal code).
- The annual loss for each insurance company over the last 10 years (only the total loss, unfortunately not the loss by postal code) normalized by the total number of buildings of that company.

From this data, I would like to estimate which postal codes are most prone to storm damage (the postal codes are not independent of each other, e.g., if storm losses are high in one postal code, then it's likely they are also increased in the neighbouring postal codes). I would assume that it is possible if n is sufficiently large. In this example, the number of postal codes is larger than the number of insurance companies.

I don't yet have a clear idea of how to do it. I could imagine that it makes sense to reduce the number of postal codes, e.g. in the most extreme case I could reduce the number of regions to two large regions (e.g. a north region and a south region) and then it would be quite simple to estimate which of the two regions is more prone to storm loss.

Is there an algorithm to do this in a more systematic way? E.g., an algorithm that automatically groups regions together?

Kind regards
Elsa

Edit: To make the problem a bit clearer:

Assume I have a 4 x 4 spatial grid and the values are a measure of the storminess (higher: increased storminess). In this example the storminess decreases from left to right. These are the values I don't know and would like to estimate/reconstruct from the data I have.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| 0.7 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.1 |
| 0.7 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.1 |
| 0.9 | 0.7 | 0.4 | 0.2 |

What I have is the distribution of buildings of various insurance companies- Here the example for one insurance company:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

This insurance company has most buildings in the left grid points. Further I have the loss ($L$) of the company which calculates as: $L = \sum S_i B_i$, where $S_i$ is the storminess at location i and $B_i$ is the fraction of buildings at location i, i.e. for this example: 0.6x0.1 + 0.4x0.1 +0.7x0.1 + 0.5x0.1 + 0.7x0.4 + 0.4x0.2 = 0.58.

I have $L$ and $B$ of different insurance companies. How can I reconstruct $S$ (and at which reslution, 2x2 or 3x3?)